# User send texts from their iphone to my email address. How do i set this up

Tags: iphone

User sends text message to my email account. I receive those messages on my iPad only. I need to receive it through email Office 365

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Please review [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for how to ask good questions and increase the chance you'll receive a helpful answer.  - From Review

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand your problem correctly, a user is sending iMessages to your Apple ID or email. A feature used to be available to do this (I believe iOS 6 or 7), but I haven't seen anything in the latest iOS. For the older iOS you could go to Settings < Messages < Receive At and choose an email from there.

Comment: This works in iOS 10 Beta 4. Just as you said, you go into Settings, Messages, Receive At... And I have my cell number and 3 email addresses selected.

Comment: As it has worked since the feature was introduced. It was never removed.

Comment: @TMHahn Interesting, I am not able to find this on my iPhone.

Comment: Go about half way down this Apple document. It was revised June 2016. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204065

Comment: @TMHahn This is not what the OP is asking for. The OP wants the messages forwarded to his email inbox. This option is no longer available in settings.

Comment: Oh, I see. I can't think of a way to do that. Agreed.